# Como coletar posts públicos de timeline no Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Olá, preciso coletar posts públicos na timeline de usuários no Facebook. Como fazer isso?

Preciso da postagem e as reações de cada postagem.

Obrigado,

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Obrigado! Estou aprendendo a utilizar a API Graph Explorer do Facebook. Eu gostaria de saber se há uma forma de recuperar os posts públicos dos usuários de uma forma automática (sem precisar por exemplo, de que usuário faça login em um aplicativo). Além disso, gostaria de um exemplo de como armazenar em um JSON esta coleta. É para um projeto de pesquisa e a ideia seria coletar estes posts públicos e analisar as reações de cada post. Contudo sou novo neste área.